# How can I prove this relation?(Number-Theory)

Tags: number-theory

$\gcd(ord(a),ord(b))=1,\:
a^i=b^j \mod n$.
Then, $a^i=1 \mod n,\: b^j=1 \mod n$

How can I prove it?

This is what I tried.

Let $ord(a)=p, ord(b)=q$. Then $a^p=1\mod n,\: b^q=1\mod n$.

And $p/\gcd(p,i) = q/\gcd(q,j)$

Actually this is just from definition, I think it is enough to show $\gcd(p,i)=p$ and $\gcd(q,j)=q$ but it is too hard for me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please take the tour http://math.stackexchange.com/tour and learn how to format math for this site http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking both sides of $a^i \equiv b^j \pmod n$ to the power of $\operatorname{ord}(b)$, we get $a^{i\operatorname{ord}(b)} \equiv 1 \pmod n$. Thus $\operatorname{ord}(a) \mid i\operatorname{ord}(b)$. As $\operatorname{gcd}(\operatorname{ord}(a),\operatorname{ord}(b)) = 1 $, we conclude that $\operatorname{ord}(a) \mid i$, which means that $a^i \equiv 1 \pmod n$.